# Asynchronous/Synchronous concurrent calls with queuing

Tags: c#, concurrency, asynchronous, task

I have a scenario where I'm doing some Actor-Model kind of messagequeing where I want a method to insert a Task or delegate into a queue (possibly the new ConcurrentQueue) , wait for some other process to process the queue, execute the task and then return the result, preferably without locking. The method might be called both synchronously and asynchronously. Only one queued action might run simultaneously

I can't wrap my head around how to accomplish this in a somewhat performant manner, please help :)

**EDIT**

Here's an attempt, anyone seeing any problems with this approach (exception handling excluded) ? Also, I can imagine this has quite a lot of overhead compared to simply locking, and how does it compare to for instance using asynchronous delegates?

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private BlockingCollection<Task<int>> blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<Task<int>>(new ConcurrentQueue<Task<int>>());
    private int i = 0;
    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();

      Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
          foreach (var task in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
            task.Start();
            task.Wait();        
          }
      });
    }


    public int Queue() {
      var task = new Task<int>(new Func<int>(DoSomething));
      this.blockingCollection.Add(task);
      task.Wait();
      return task.Result;
    }

    public int DoSomething() {
      return Interlocked.Increment(ref this.i);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.Write(this.Queue()));
    }


  }
```

Comment: What is the gap between the TPL Task parallel library from the framework and your requirement? The queue is just handled by the framework and there are different synchronisation alternatives depending on your requirements.

Comment: You may want to look at the SmartThreadPool library (http://smartthreadpool.codeplex.com/), it may fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The TPL should do that for you - just call `Wait()` on your `Task<T>` - however, there is no way to do this without blocking; by definition, in your scenario that is *exactly want you want to do*. Blocking *might* be implemented via a `lock`, but there are other ways too - the TPL hides this. Personally, in a similar scenario I do it with a custom queue and a mini-pool of objects I can use to lock against (never exposed outside the wrapper).

You might also want to look at the C# 5 async/await stuff.

But note: if you aren't going to do anything useful while you are waiting, you might as well run that code directly on the current thread - unless the issue is thread-bound, for example a multiplexer. If you are interested, later today (or over the weekend) I intend releasing the multiplexer that stackoverflow uses to talk to redis, which (in synchronous mode, at least) has exactly the problems you describe.

As a side note; if you can work with a *callback* (from the other thread), and not have to *wait* on completion, that can be more efficient overall. But it doesn't fit every scenario.